# Publish Entity-Framework Code-First Migrations with no Context in the startup project

Tags: entity-framework, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am building a solution with the following Projects:

- `Main.Data` - Class Library project
- `Main.API` - Asp.NET MVC WebApi - references Main.Data
- `Main` - Asp.NET MVC 4 web application - references Main.API

I have a `MyContext : DbContext` class located inside `Main.Data` project.
I have also successfully issues `enable-migrations`console command on `Main.Data` project, and I am successfully using LocalDB as an SQL server for my data and for `upgrade-database` migrations.

The problem starts when I am trying to publish `Main` project to Windows Azure website.

The Publish Profile that is automatically created using `Import from a Windows Azure web site` does not seems to recognize that I am using Entity Framework Code First solution, and so I can't enable `Execute Code First Migrations` as I would like to. 
Instead, I can only enable `Update database` scripts.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with Entity Framework 5.0.0 (Since the beginning of the project).

Just to verify, I have tried to add a temporary `MyContext` class inside the `Main` Project and to `enable-migrations` on the `Main` project, and after that my Publish Profile automatically detected Entity Framework Code-First.
That is, of-course, not a solution (or is it?)

Here are some relevant threads:

- [This](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/) is the base learning tutorial.
- [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698#efcfmigrations) explains deployment options, but no troubleshooting.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230902/publishing-my-database-package-deploy-with-code-first-migrations/) actually gives a few ideas to try, but all seems unnatural.

I am looking for a clean stable solution. Do I have to put my Context class inside the Main Project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you remember to add the app / web.config to your Main project? When you enable migrations it add the config files to the Main.Data project. These are not added when you reference the project. I have my contexts in seperate projects, but the config files should be in the project that i use them in?

Comment: Yes, web.config is located on the Main project, and the configuration files are on Main.Data... Did you manage to deploy the Main project to Azure?

Comment: My setup is not 100% identical. I do all the migration stuff in visual studio and local. When i deploy, my databases are up to date and things just work. havent tried with automatic migrations

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can now enable `Execute Code First Migrations` when I create a publish profile.
Here is what I did to achieve it:

1. Inside `Main/Web.config` I changed the name of the connection string to the FQN of the context class: `Main.Data.MyContext`.
2. Add a reference from `Main` project to `Main.Data` Project (which was not needed until now).

This does the job for me.
If anyone got a better or more educating answer, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: Main.Data.MyContext would be the [Fully Qualified Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which is different from the "full path" (which would be something like the file system path.)

Comment: In order to use my existing publish profiles (.pubxml) I had to go into them and manually update the `<ObjectGroup name="...">`.  Probably recreating them would have worked, too.  Thanks!

Comment: This did not work for me :(. @Liel did you do anything else to make it work?