# Azure: Unable to execute code first migrations on publishing .net core application

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure, .net-core, ef-code-first

I am getting started with Azure (coming from AWS) and for the most part, have found it remarkably easy to use. However, I've currently encountered an issue where I am unable to execute my code first migrations in my .net core/EF core solution. Everything I read, saids that I should have an object to `Execute code first migrations` in the publish wizard but I do not see this option anywhere.

Screenshot of my publish options:
[image]

And a screenshot of the publish options everyone else in the world seems to have:
[image]

To set up the publish profiles, I right clicked the api project in my solution, clicked publish, selected App Service then clicked Select Existing and chose the app service I had already created. The deployment worked fine other than not running code first migrations.

How can I overcome this? What am I missing here?

My GUESS is that it relates to the architecture of the project which looks as follows:

API Project -> Services Project -> Data Project

where the data project contains the context. perhaps this issue arises from the fact that my API project has no direct reference to the project that contains the data project? If this is the cause, I'm still at a loss for how to fix it as not having a direct reference is intentionally done as an architectual constraint.

UPDATE: adding a reference from the api project which is being published to the data project where my DbContext lives did NOT fix the issue

I have also tried numerous suggestions such as those listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543229/publish-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-with-no-context-in-the-startup-pr?rq=1)

Comment: Perhaps that wizard doesn't support EF Core yet.

Comment: so is my only option to script teh db schema and run the script against my live server? surely there must be a better way

Comment: You can run the migration from your dev environment, or run it explicitly on startup of your web application.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#apply-migrations-at-runtime